# Wavefunction Basis Formalism

Tags: wavefunction, fermions

If we have two electrons and two possible states $| 1 \rangle$ and $| 2 \rangle$, a possible state, as I understand, could be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(| 1 \rangle | 2 \rangle - | 2 \rangle| 1\rangle)$.  Why isn't this $0$?  I know that it isn't, but physically, why isn't

$$| 1 \rangle | 2 \rangle - | 2 \rangle| 1 \rangle \stackrel{?}{=} 0$$

Comment: If $V$ is the space spanned by $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ then $|1\rangle|2\rangle$ is shorthand for $1\rangle\otimes 2\rangle$ in the tensor product space $V\otimes V$, which has to be the universal recipient of a bilinear map from $V\times V$.  So consider, for example, the bilinear map that takes $(v,w)$ to $v_1w_2$, where $v_i$ is the projection of  $v$ on $|i\rangle$.  This vanishes on $(|2\rangle,|1\rangle)$ but  not on $(|1\rangle,|2\rangle)$, so $|1\rangle\otimes |2\rangle-|2\rangle\otimes |1\rangle$ cannot be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\vert 1\rangle \vert 2\rangle$ is the state where the first electron is in state $\vert 1\rangle$ and the second is in state $\vert 2\rangle$, while $\vert 2\rangle \vert 1\rangle$ is the opposite. So they are not the same state, that is $\vert 1\rangle \vert 2\rangle\neq\vert 2\rangle \vert 1\rangle$, or $\vert 1\rangle \vert 2\rangle-\vert 2\rangle \vert 1\rangle\neq0$.

(this may confuse you if consider also particle indistinguishability, in that case you may benefit from checking out [Identical particles - Quantum mechanical description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles#Quantum_mechanical_description); the point is that if the two electrons are indistinguishable then an acceptable physical state *cannot be* $\vert 1\rangle \vert 2\rangle$, precisely because otherwise you would be able to distinguish them!)

Comment: Are you sure this is true? for example, the ground state wave function (considering symmetric spin) of a harmonic oscillator of two identical fermions would be A(|1>|2>-|2>|1>), so its two indistinguishable fermions in different states

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand your reply, maybe you could elaborate a bit more? Anyway, mathematically is due to the fact $v_1\otimes v_2$ is different from $v_2\otimes v_1$, even if the two vectors lie in the same vector space

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the most obvious way to see it's not zero is to use a coordinate basis, so that you state would be (ignoring the $\sqrt{2}$):
$$
\Psi(x_1,x_2)=\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)-\phi(x_1)\psi(x_2)
$$
Of course this is not $0$ unless the function $\phi$ is the same as the function $\psi$.  You can call $\psi\to \xi_1$ and $\phi\to \xi_2$ to make the correspondence 
$$
\langle x_i\vert k \rangle = \xi_k(x_i)\, ,\quad k=1,2
$$
complete.

The most that can be said is that $\Psi(x,x)=0$, reflecting the antisymmetry of the wavefunction.